# Is it possible to set pre-processor conditions within a macro?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, c-preprocessor, substitution

I'm in a position where this design would greatly improve the clarity and maintenance-needs for my code.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
#define MY_MACRO(arg) #if (arg)>0 cout<<((arg)*5.0)<<endl; #else cout<<((arg)/5.0)<<endl; #endif
```

**The idea here:**
The pre-processor substitutes different lines of code depending on the compile-time (constant) value of the macro argument. Of course, I know this syntax doesn't work, as the `#` is seen as the string-ize operator instead of the standard `#if`, but I think this demonstrates the pre-processor *functionality* I am trying to achieve.

I know that I could just put a standard `if` statement in there, and the compiler/runtime would be left to check the value. But this is unnecessary work for the application when `arg` will always be passed a constant value, like `10.8` or `-12.5` that only needs to be evaluated at compile-time.

Performance needs for this number-crunching application require that all unnecessary runtime conditions be eliminated whenever possible, and many constant values and macros have been used (in place of variables and functions) to make this happen. The ability to continue this trend without having to mix pre-processor code with real `if` conditions would make this much cleaner - and, of course, code-cleanliness is one of the biggest concerns when using macros, especially at this level.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot have `#if` (or anything similar) inside your macro.
However, if the condition is known at compile-time, you can safetly use a normal `if` statement. The compiler will optimise it (assuming you have optimisions turned on).

It's called "[Dead code elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination)"

Comment: Even better, I'll use the ?: operator for to "inline" the condition entirely. All in all, I agree that this will probably be the best and only option.

Comment: Just be careful, using ?: too much can make your code hard to follow!

Comment: Point taken. Dead code is generally seen the same way, regardless whether you use ?: or `if`, so clarity should be a consideration.

Comment: Dead code must still compile. This can be a pain in code like `if (i>0) { int foo[i]; } else { int foo[1-i]; }`. Templates are an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Simple, use real C++:

```
template <bool B> void foo_impl       (int arg) { cout << arg*5.0 << endl; }
template < >      void foo_impl<false>(int arg) { cout << arg/5.0 << endl; }
template <int I>  void foo            ( )       { foo_impl< (I>0) >(I); }
```

[edit]
Or in modern C++, `if constexpr`.

Comment: Although I admit it's harder for floating-point numbers, since you can't pass them as template parameters. You can still use the `foo_impl< (F>0) >(F);` part though, even from a macro.

Comment: I favor real code (OOP or otherwise, like your example) over macros anyday. The unfortunate truth: the example I gave in the question is verrry simplified. My actual code is much larger than this, and would be impossible to debug in template-form. The reason macros are better in this particular case is due to the fact that any other solution would require me to write the same code files dozens and dozens of times. Add templates to the mix, and you have some guaranteed un-maintainable code. Macros allow me to write the code once, and replicate it as many times as I need.

Comment: That I don't buy. Templates are impossible to debug, but macros are? Debuggers are far, far better at understanding template functions. They just have a funky mangled name, that's all. More maintainable? Templates respect scope far better. Write once, use often? Sure, templates do that too. But yes, you'll have to relearn some methods.